# Rails:NoMethodError at /projects/2/model/new undefined method `name' for []:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error after creating new model parameters:
This is app/views/model/parameterarea.html.haml

[parameterarea.html.haml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ00f.png)

This is my Model controller:

```
class ModelController < ApplicationController
    skip_authorization_check

    def index
        @hostname = request.host 
        @hostport = request.port.to_s
        @model = Model.all
        @user_relations =Relation.where(user_id: current_user)
        @p_id = get_project_id
    end 

    def new
        @model=Model.new
        @p_id=get_project_id
    end

    def create
        @model = Model.new(m_params)
        if @model.name.strip.length != 0
            if @model.save
                redirect_to  project_model_index_path, notice: 'Model was successfully created.'
            else 
                render 'new'
            end
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end


    def destroy

    end


end

    def show 
        @hostname = request.host 
        @hostport = request.port.to_s

    end


    def update

    end


    def get_project_id
        params[:project_id]
    end

    def m_params
        params.require(:model).permit(:name,:description,:response, model_params_attributes: [:id, :name, :data_type, :_destroy])
    end


    def get_id
    params[:id]
  end
```

This is my model:

```
class ModelParam < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :model, optional: true


    enum data_type: {
        String:            0,
        Integer:           1,
        Bool:              2,
        Hash:              3,
        Date:              4,
        Datetime:          5,
        Float:             6,
        Decimal:           7,
        Text:              8,
        Time:              9,
        # "Array[]":         10,
        File:              11,
        Image:             12,
        "Array[String]":   13,
        "Array[Integer]":  14,
        "Array[Bool]":     15,
        "Array[Hash]":     16,
        "Array[Date]":     17,
        "Array[Datetime]": 18,
        "Array[Float]":    19,
        "Array[Decimal]":  20,
        "Array[Text]":     21,
        "Array[Time]":     22,
        "Array[File]":     23,
        "Array[Image]":    24
    }

end
```

Comment: In your create action, ` @model = Model.new(m_params)` @model is array  ?

Comment: Give us the exact error message (file/line) and post the view source code as text, not as an image please

Comment: I should add accepts_nested_attributes_for :model_params into my model.rb

Comment: Model is not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only fix it to add below line into **model.rb**

```
"accepts_nested_attributes_for :model_params"
```